# Поиск нужной группировки для запроса

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Добрый день, пытаюсь сделать запрос для метрики, который выводит число визитов сайта за каждый день из определенного отрезка(неделя, месяц и.т.д.), но не могу найти нужную группировку, выводит лишь общее число визитов за весь промежуток.
Вот мои метрики и группировки: 
"dimensions" : [ "ym:s:gender" ],
"metrics" : [ "ym:s:visits", "ym:s:users", "ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds" ],
"sort" : [ "-ym:s:visits" ]

Comment: Вопрос решен, оказывается надо было добавить bytime в запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, оказывается надо было добавить bytime в запрос.